# Regex match Nth occurence to end of string

Tags: python, regex

I'm pulling my hair out trying to parse a National Weather Service Alert using Regex in Python. How can I match from the last * to the end of the string?

```
The Flash Flood Watch continues for

* Portions of northeastern and central X, Y, and Z.

* Until midnight EDT tonight

* Areas of heavy rain will continue for areas near and east of Interstate 95 this evening as showers and thunderstorms slowly move through. Some areas could receive an additional 1 to 3 inches of rain, which could result in flash flooding of small streams and creeks as well as urban areas.
```

Comment: If you are reading from file, something like `if line.startswith('*'):` would do. Please edit to include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the following regex pattern:

```
\*[^*]+$
```

This would match from the final star until the end of the input.  The exact regex and settings you would use depends on the particular tool/language you are using.

Comment: Solved, thanks. Modified to (?<=\* )[^*]+$ to skip over the * and first space.

Comment: @blahbluey You could also have used `\*([^*]+)$`, and then accessed the first capture group, assuming your regex engine supports it.

Comment: Wonderful answer @TimBiegeleisen. Just in case OP might miss single line flag. `(?s)\*[^*]+$`

Comment: The NWS can't pick a consistent format to save its life. In some circumstances there is a fourth * and (?<=* )[^*]+$ only captures the last one. Is there a way to grab specifically from the third * onward if there are more? I'm in python if it matters.

Comment: I won't edit my answer because now you have invalidated it by changing the question.  There is no "third" bullet point unless we can look ahead and see one more `*`, so your new requirement is vague.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought I understood my requirement but then the format changed further into the set. I'll post a new question.

Comment: @blahbluey You don't need to post another question. Use `findall()` method which gives you the data in list and use it as arrays. Please see the demo [**here**](https://repl.it/@mAndY80SS/JampackedAdoredCoordinates)

Comment: `[^*]+$` is sufficient as long as the multiline flag is not set.

Comment: I did the easy part. Please thank @TimBiegeleisen and CarySwoveland also for their wonderful regex.